# php mail sending email when page is loaded

Tags: php, html

Problem: I have written html code for a form and php to email the contents of the form, however the php code runs as soon as the page loads resulting in a blank email being sent, this is despite my checkin if the form has been submitted using  `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`

also, for some bizarre reason if I remove the line 'echo"hello";' the php code doesn't work at all!

Here is the php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    echo"hello";

/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail = "contact@birminghamvegans.com";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$name = $_POST['inputName'];
$email = $_POST['inputEmail'];
$subject = $_POST['inputSubject'];
$message = $_POST['inputMessage'];



/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */

$subject2 = "Message from Birmingham Vegans website";

$message = "

Someone has sent you a message using your contact form:

Name: $name
Email: $email
Subject: $subject

Message:
$message

";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject2, $message);


?>
```

and here is the HTML

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="Your Name" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Your Email" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputSubject" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Subject</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSubject" name="inputSubject" placeholder="Subject Message" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputPassword1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="inputMessage" name="inputMessage" placeholder="Your message..." required></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                                        Send Message
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Comment: You need to surround your code block with curly braces after the if. Without that, the if only applies to the next, single line.

Comment: Wrap the PHP code in `{ }`

Comment: it is a syntax issue due to the single line after the if statement without curly braces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the code breaks when you remove `echo"hello";` is because you're missing brackets for your `IF` statement which is  a syntax error. When you have one line after a control structure like `IF`  it is assumed that is all that is in that block and is valid code. Once you have more than two lines curly braces are *required*.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // mail code goes here
}
```

The reason why your email is sent on page load is because you have the email portion of code called on every page load. If you fix your if statement to include curly braces this error goes away.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is missing brackets on the opening `if`

This is a complete statement:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
   echo"hello";
```

It's the same as this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo"hello";
}
```

So to fix your issue use brackets on your `if` statement:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   echo"hello";

  /* Set e-mail recipient */
  $myemail = "contact@birminghamvegans.com";

  /* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
  $name = $_POST['inputName'];
  $email = $_POST['inputEmail'];
  $subject = $_POST['inputSubject'];
  $message = $_POST['inputMessage'];

  /* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */

  $subject2 = "Message from Birmingham Vegans website";

  $message = "

  Someone has sent you a message using your contact form:

  Name: $name
  Email: $email
  Subject: $subject

  Message:
  $message

  ";

  /* Send the message using mail() function */
  mail($myemail, $subject2, $message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    echo"hello";
```

's if statement only applies to the next line without curly braces(`{...}`). Because of that the `mail()` function is executed regardless of form submission.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the conditional block of code in curly braces. Without braces you are applying the condition to only the echo statement (the next statement after the condition) and running the rest of the code every time.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // Inside opening curly brace
    echo"hello";

/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail = "contact@birminghamvegans.com";

//
// More conditional code here
//

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject2, $message);

// Closing brace
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, the curly braces was a schoolboy error. Worked out the error, needed todo `if (isset($_POST['inputName']))`